# Make dictionaries in list of dictionaries equal length

Tags: python

Assuming a list of dictionaries with unequal length, what's the best way to make them equal length i.e. for the missing key-value, add key but with value set to empty string or null:

```
lst = [
  {'id': '123', 'name': 'john'},
  {'id': '121', 'name': 'jane'},
  {'id': '121'}, 
  {'name': 'mary'}
]
```

to become:

```
lst = [
  {'id': '123', 'name': 'john'},
  {'id': '121', 'name': 'jane'},
  {'id': '121', 'name': ''}, 
  {'id': '', 'name': 'mary'}
]
```

The only way I can think of is converting to pandas dataframe then back to dict:

```
pd.DataFrame(lst).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: Can you supply a preexisting list or set of the keys, or must they be extracted dynamically from `lst`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding all the keys requires a full initial pass of the data:

```
>>> set().union(*lst)
{'id', 'name'}
```

Now iterate the dicts and set default for each key:

```
keys = set().union(*lst)
for d in lst:
    for k in keys:
        d.setdefault(k, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `colleections.ChainMap` to get all the keys:

```
>>> lst = [
...   {'id': '123', 'name': 'john'},
...   {'id': '121', 'name': 'jane'},
...   {'id': '121'}, 
...   {'name': 'mary'}
... ] 
>>> 
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> 
>>> for k in ChainMap(*lst):
...     for d in lst:
...         _ = d.setdefault(k, '')
... 
>>> lst
[{'id': '123', 'name': 'john'}, {'id': '121', 'name': 'jane'}, {'id': '121', 'name': ''}, {'name': 'mary', 'id': ''}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this snippet

```
lst = [
    {'id': '123', 'name': 'john'},
    {'id': '121', 'name': 'jane'},
    {'id': '121'}, 
    {'name': 'mary'}
] 
for data in lst:
     if "name" not in data:
         data["name"] = ""
     if "id" not in data:
         data["id"] = ""


print(lst)
```

Comment: This is the fastest of the solutions with this example input, by a long way, and happens to also be the most readable.

Comment: OP made a good MCVE.  Will it still be the most readable when generalised to more than 2 keys?

Comment: @wim...agreed. Though the solution is correct for this question, its not MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (Python 3.5+).

```
>>> all_keys = set(key for d in lst for key in d)
>>> [{**dict.fromkeys(all_keys, ''), **d} for d in lst]
[{'id': '123', 'name': 'john'}, {'id': '121', 'name': 'jane'}, {'id': '121', 'name': ''}, {'id': '', 'name': 'mary'}]
```

(Note that the unpacking order is critical here, you must unpack `d` after the dictionary with the default values in order to override the default values.)